# Issues with using IloCP with too many workers

Tags: constraint-programming, ilog, cp-optimizer

I have built a simple constraint enforcing that the value of a variable must be consistent with a modulo operation. Two consistency levels are available: bounds consistency and domain consistency. In this example, solving the problem with bounds consistency works well with 1 or 2 workers, but with 3 or more workers the `propagate()` function loops infinitely since it appears to be unable to remove the maximum value of the domain. My computer has 2 physical cores, so my guess is that using more workers than physical cores is the problem. I am using the latest version of Cplex Optimization Studio. Here is the code:

File `main.cc`:

```
#include <ilcp/cp.h>
#include "IloModulo.h"


int main() {
  IloEnv env;
  IloModel model(env);

  IloIntVar x(env, 1, 100000);
  model.add(IloModulo(env, x, 3, BOUNDS_CONSISTENCY));
  model.add(IloMinimize(env, x));

  IloCP solver(model);
  solver.setParameter(IloCP::Workers, 1); // Infinite loop with 3 or more workers
  solver.solve();

  return 0;
}
```

File `IloModulo.h`:

```
#ifndef ILOMODULO_H_
#define ILOMODULO_H_


#include <ilcp/cpext.h>


#define BOUNDS_CONSISTENCY 1
#define DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY 2


class IlcModuloI : public IlcConstraintI {
private:
  IlcIntVar x_;
  IlcInt modulo_;
  IlcInt consistency_;

public:
  IlcModuloI(IloCPEngine cp,
         IlcIntVar x,
         IlcInt modulo,
         IlcInt consistency);
  ~IlcModuloI();

  virtual void propagate();
  virtual void post();
};

// The IloModulo constraint is used with the following function
IloConstraint IloModulo(IloEnv env,
            IloIntVar x,
            IloInt modulo,
            IloInt consistency);


#endif // ILOMODULO_H_
```

File `IloModulo.cc`:

```
#include "IloModulo.h"


IlcModuloI::IlcModuloI(IloCPEngine solver,
               IlcIntVar x,
               IlcInt modulo,
               IlcInt consistency) :
  IlcConstraintI(solver),
  modulo_(modulo),
  x_(x),
  consistency_(consistency) {
  ;
}


IlcModuloI::~IlcModuloI() {
  ;
}


void IlcModuloI::propagate() {
  switch (consistency_) {
  case BOUNDS_CONSISTENCY: {
    while ((x_.getMin() % modulo_ != 0) ||
       (x_.getMax() % modulo_ != 0)) {
      if (x_.getMin() % modulo_ != 0) {
    x_.setMin(x_.getMin()+1);
    continue;
      }
      if (x_.getMax() % modulo_ != 0) {
    std::cout << "Min/max values: " << x_.getMin() << "/" << x_.getMax() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Decreasing maximum value by 1." << std::endl;
    x_.setMax(x_.getMax()-1);
    std::cout << "Min/max values: " << x_.getMin() << "/" << x_.getMax() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------" << std::endl;
    continue;
      }
    }
    break;
  }

  case DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY: {
    IlcInt threshold = x_.getMin();
    while (threshold <= x_.getMax()) {
      if (threshold % modulo_ != 0) {
    x_.removeValue(threshold);
      }
      if (threshold == x_.getMax()) {
    break;
      }
      threshold = x_.getNextHigher(threshold);
    }
    break;
  }
  }
}


void IlcModuloI::post() {
  switch (consistency_) {
  case BOUNDS_CONSISTENCY: {
    x_.whenRange(this);
    break;
  }

  case DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY: {
    x_.whenDomain(this);
    break;
  }
  }
}


ILOCPCONSTRAINTWRAPPER3(IloModuloWrapper, solver,
            IloIntVar, x_,
            IloInt, modulo_,
            IloInt, consistency_) {
  use(solver, x_);
  return new (solver.getHeap()) IlcModuloI(solver,
                       solver.getIntVar(x_),
                       modulo_,
                       consistency_);
}


IloConstraint IloModulo(IloEnv env,
            IloIntVar x,
            IloInt modulo,
            IloInt consistency) {
  return IloModuloWrapper(env, x, modulo, consistency);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it really seems to be an issue with the propagation of user defined constraints in some very specific conditions. I'm not sure if there is a direct link with the number of workers. The development team of CP Optimizer will investigate this problem and we will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no problem in CP Optimizer, the problem comes from the ‘while’ loop in the propagation. During propagation, when you change the min/max of a variable, the change is not necessarily applied immediately, so if you do x.setMax(x.getMax()-1), the new max is not applied immediately and in the same propagate(), x.getMax() still returns the ‘old’ max value. This is the reason for the loop. So if you really want to remove the values one by one like in your current algorithm, you should store the current bounds:

```
case BOUNDS_CONSISTENCY: {
  IloInt min = x_.getMin();
  IloInt max = x_.getMax();
  while ((min % modulo_ != 0) || (max % modulo_ != 0)) {
    if (min % modulo_ != 0) {
      min += 1;
      x_.setMin(min);
      continue;
    }
    if (max % modulo_ != 0) {
      max -=1;
      x_.setMax(max);
      continue;
    }
  }
```

But of course, you do not need to work by increments and you could directly set the right min/max bounds using integer division:

```
IloInt min = x_.getMin();
IloInt max = x_.getMax();
min = ( (min+_modulo-1) / _modulo) * _modulo;
max = ( (max) / _modulo) * _modulo;
x_.setRange(min, max);
```

And of course (but I don’t know what is the context of your question), you do not need to define a new constraint, you can just use the predefined modulo expressions in the model, that is, posting:

```
model.add( (x % _modulo)==0 );
```

At the concert level.

Comment: This was actually just a toy constraint to try some things out, but yes, the predefined modulo operation would do the trick.